# Ignore substring in regex match

Tags: regex, substring, notepad++

I'm writing a function list parser for Notepad++ to add support for Nasal.

I'm using the following regular expression:

`^[\t ]*(var[\n\s]+)?([_A-Za-z]?[\w_]*)[\n\s]*=[\n\s]*func[\n\s]*(\([^\)\(]*\))?`: [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JNXNd5AKRTwEGoFd)

... to match these 2 types of valid declarations:

1. `foo = func...`
2. `var foo = func...`

To further extract the function name `foo` from the matches of this regex, the best I could come up with was:

`(var[\n\s]+)?([_A-Za-z]?[\w_]*)`: [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/c_2IbrVzQjLjwtP6)

Using this matches "foo" or "var foo", as the case may be. What is a regex that can ignore the presence of the substring `var[\n\s]+]`, so it only extracts "foo" for the function list?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\K` feature that removes all on the left from the match result:

```
(?:var\s+)?\K([A-Za-z_]\w*)\s*=\s*([A-Za-z_]\w*)
```

*(Note that this feature is only available in recent versions of np++)*

Answer (score 0):

Get the matched group from index 2.

```
(\bvar\b)?\s\s*(\w+)\s\s*=\s\s*func\b
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV2sP1/4)